# how to do mathematical calculation in mysql?

Tags: mysql, math, distance

Lets say I have a table like this

```
ID   Point   x     y     z
---  ----   ---   ---   ---
1     A      3     2     1    
2     B      1     3     2
3     C      2     4     1
4     D      1     3     3
5     E      5     1     2
```

I want to get the nearest point to N which in `(x,y,z) = (1,2,3)`

To get the nearest point, we need euclidean distance formula. 
Lets say, squareroot of `[(N(x)-data(x))^2 + (N(y)-data(y))^2 + (N(z)-data(z))^2]`

How do I do the query contains the euclidean distance formula to select the rows I want?

Comment: you dont need to minimize the square root, can just minimise the sum of squares, as this will give you the closest point..

Comment: could you write the query about your suggestion?

Comment: see @Gordon Linoff s answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by power(x - 1, 2) + power(y - 2, 2) + power(z - 3, 2)
limit 1;
```

As mentioned in a comment, you don't actually need the square root, because the ordering is the same.

By the way, you can put the calculation in the `select` so you can return the distance:

```
select t.*,
       sqrt(power(x - 1, 2) + power(y - 2, 2) + power(z - 3, 2)) as distance
from table t
order by distance
limit 1;
```

Comment: is power the sql syntax for pow? okay I'll try. thanks for the answer.

Comment: @rfa . . . MySQL supports both `pow()` and `power()`.  I've seen `power()` in other databases, but I don't recall `pow()`.